# Create DB script of all the DB changes took place in defined period

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, database-replication

**Problem Description:**

In my project, I had to create the DB scripts of all the changes that took place in Development DB from the start date of sprint till the end date.

These DB scripts will be then executed on the Production environment.

Changes to include in the DB scripts are:

- All DDL
- DML on only master tables(I have a list of MASTER tables in one table)

Note:

- There must be one `.sql` file per object <-- This is unique requirement of our customer
- For DDL changes and DML changes on the same objects, there must be two .sql files
- Name of the file should be like `DDL_<Object_name>.sql` for DDL changes and `DML_<Object_name>.sql` for DML changes.

**Currently How I do it:**

I have used `EXTENDED [AUDIT][1]` feature of the Oracle to store the SQL statements that were executed on required objects.

I have created the Procedure which takes the start and end dates as an input parameter. Then it fetches the DB changes one by one - order by Object name, Type of SQL (DDL, DML), execution date then loop through it and create the files according to statement type(DDL or DML) and write the statement in that file.

**Expectation:**

I am able to achieve what is expected(In the first phase) but I want to know If there are some tool or Utility or Readily available Scripts or any other ways, using which I can achieve the same result?

Thanks for the Help.

Comment: The correct approach is to write DDL and DML scripts, run those scripts in Development then stash 'em in a source control database. No post hoc tooling beats doing it correctly in the first place.

Comment: @APC, **The correct approach is to write DDL and DML scripts** --> Means manually?

Comment: Unless you're using a modelling tool to generate the DDL from a model.

Comment: To add to APC's comments, blindly applying everything that was done to a dev database to upper environments is dangerous.  Inevitably, people create objects that they end up not needing or that are needed, making changes that get abandoned either because the story gets moved to a different sprint or because the approach was wrong, etc.  Pushing those changes up to the next environment just creates more problems.  Developers need to identify the changes that actually relate to the stories you want to promote.

Comment: Nope, we do not blindly apply it on production. We can review it before sending it to production. Do anyone know how to do it?

Comment: You could parse out the statements from the DB log files. Not elegant, but effective.